# Show elements from array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm new in web development. I converted the list of image names to an array by following codeL

```
var image_array = $("#image-ul img").map(function() {return $(this).attr("src");});
```

Now I want to show some of these images. I show all the images by adding following codeL

```
$('#image-ul img').css('display','block');
```

But I want some of the images, like the following:

```
for (var i=0; i<2; i++) { $('#image-ul img:image_array[i]').css('display','block');}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what means by 'some of'?

Comment: some from image_array

Comment: some of images mens which images..please specify.. it will help to give ans

Comment: actually i have 5 images and want to show 2 of them

Comment: Side note: use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of toggling the display property.

Comment: It makes no sense to get the image source for all images in a map, and then use a for loop to select the images based on the source in a map you just got from the same elements etc? You could'nt jump thru more hoops even if you tried!

Answer (score 3):

You don't really use a for loop to do that, you select the images and limit the selection with `eq()`, `lt()`, `gt()` etc. So for anyting with an index lower than 2, you do :

```
$('#image-ul img:lt(2)').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
for (var i=0; i<2; i++) { $('#image-ul img:image_array[i]').css('display','block');}
```

to this

```
for (var i=0; i<2; i++) { $('#image-ul img').eq(i).show(); }
```

as Juhana pointed out `.show()` is the best way to show display an element with jQuery

Comment: it is my desired answer.Thanks

Comment: @andDev my example is just a way for you to get the desired effect from your code, however Adeneo has shown a much more efficient way of achieving what you're after

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for (var i=0; i<2; i++) { $('#image-ul img:eq(' + i +')').css('display','block');}
```

Or

```
for (var i=0; i<2; i++) { $('#image-ul img').eq(i).css('display','block');}
```